# Giving domain user RetainIndefinitely permissions through tfssecurity

Tags: tfsbuild

I'm getting nowhere slowly using tfssecurity.exe to programatically give a user the retainindefinitly permission on a TFS build definition.

I'm using TFS2010 and the command line

```
tfssecurity /a+ Build [teamprojectname] RetainIndefinitely n:domain\user ALLOW /collection:http://mytfsserver:8080/tfs/collectionname
```

and it's saying done and showing the ACL for the object.

But it just doesn't change anything in the Team Explorer window, and permissions are not changed for the user.

I know something is wrong, probably with my token as I can't list any existing ACL's either using the /acl switch, but information on this is quite, well, non-existent.

Any help would be most appreciated.

Thanks.

Alan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: this appears to be a TFS bug, and can't be done. Your command is good, but TFS does not process it as expected.

Long answer: I have been attempting a similar command (Windows 7 x64, Visual Studio 2010 SP1, TFS 2010), and encountered the same issue. Microsoft technical support was able to reproduce the problem, and a bug has been submitted to the Visual Studio development team at Microsoft.

You can see the bug report here, and indicate that you can reproduce it, here:

- https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/731203/tfssecurity-a-build-command-line-to-assign-privileges-does-not-assign-privileges

Comment: Pity really, everything else on our "add a new Team Project" script works really well but we need to do this manually.  Many thanks for your answer, I've added my vote on the bug report.